# Rails: Foundation-Icons should work in production... but it doesn't

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, production-environment

I followed every single tutorial on internet to make foundation icons work in production mode but I failed every time.
I do not want to use any gemify css library, that will simply not work if rails does not serve the assets.

```
#app/assets/fonts
       - foundation-icons.eot
       - foundation-icons.svg
       - foundation-icons.ttf
       - foundation-icons.woff

#app/assets/stylesheets/foundation-icons
@font-face {
  font-family: "foundation-icons";
  src: font-url("foundation-icons.eot");
  src: font-url("foundation-icons.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"),
       font-url("foundation-icons.woff") format("woff"),
       font-url("foundation-icons.ttf") format("truetype"),
       font-url("foundation-icons.svg#fontcustom") format("svg");
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
.fi-address-book:before,
....

#config/application.rb
config.assets.precompile << /\.(?:svg|eot|woff|ttf)$/
```

If I run the command:

```
RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile
```

I obtain:

```
#public/assets/
        - foundation-icons-7eadaa6a15e069d84c07540345524b0e.eot
        - foundation-icons-7eadaa6a15e069d84c07540345524b0e.ttf
        - foundation-icons-7eadaa6a15e069d84c07540345524b0e.woff
        - foundation-icons-ffbd67b2dc2f5e03fca68691f97f051d.svg
```

My page layout will render the sprokets manifest

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "main/manifest/about_manifest" %>
```

that contain the lines:

```
 *= require foundation_and_overrides
 *= require foundation-icons
```

If I take a look to my about_manifest-90e09360ea22dff94eb45a5550df521b.css

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "foundation-icons";
  src: url(/assets/foundation-icons-7eadaa6a15e069d84c07540345524b0e.eot);
  src: url(/assets/foundation-icons-7eadaa6a15e069d84c07540345524b0e.eot?#iefix) format("embedded-opentype"), url(/assets/foundation-icons-7eadaa6a15e069d84c07540345524b0e.woff) format("woff"), url(/assets/foundation-icons-7eadaa6a15e069d84c07540345524b0e.ttf) format("truetype"), url(/assets/foundation-icons-ffbd67b2dc2f5e03fca68691f97f051d.svg#fontcustom) format("svg");
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal; }
```

When I run in production with

```
RAILS_ENV=production rails s
```

I have no warning in my chrome console. All assets are found but my icons looks like squares.
The code to include the icon is

```
<i class="fi-mail"></i>

#production.rb
config.serve_static_assets = true #This one will be false with passenger
config.assets.digest = true
config.assets.compile = false
```

Please help.
PS: I should say also that I use a custom font for my text and it work perfectly.

Comment: Did you have a try of clearing browser cache?

Comment: I can not believe it! It worked thanks :-) but how could it be? I have precompiled the font many times and usually they get a different digest code every time so how can my browser cache it for so long?